# Use Switch button to toggle dayNight theme

Tags: android, button, android-widget, android-theme

I have implemented a **Switch button** in my layout and want to use Android **dayNight theme** using the button, dayNight theme works okay but the problem is that when ever I **click the switch it does not work instantly**, i have to **change activities** and then it works, **for example** if I click on switch in one activity it will not do anything until i press the back button and move to some other activity and again come back to that activity and also my switch state always set to default when ever I change my activity and comeback, please help

> I am using Android Studio with dayNight theme

**Below is my Switch Activity**

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setContentView(R.layout.settings_page);
        DayNightt = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.dayNight_Switch);
        DayNightt.setChecked(false);
        DayNightt.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);

                }else{
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                }
            }
        });
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

**XML Switch Activity**

```
<Switch
        android:id="@+id/dayNight_Switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="Switch" />
```

Answer (score 1):

after **change** the **switch** add this method:

```
super.recreate();
```

This **recreates** the **activity** and if work fine sets the **correct theme**.

Some like that:

```
DayNightt.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    super.recreate();
                    //Or this
                    recreate();

                }else{
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    super.recreate();
                    //Or this
                    recreate();
                }
            }
        });
```

**UPDATE**:

If the **first method** not Works you can try this:

```
DayNightt.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
                    getActivity().finish();
                    startActivity(intent);

                }else{
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
                    getActivity().finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

**note**: this second way for me is not the best but you can try.

Comment: super.recreate() does not work for my case and recreate just freeze the app when I click the switch button

Comment: try add the code after super.oncreate() of activity.

Comment: no sir, it still freeze :( can there be any other alternative?

Comment: @RohitB I update my answer with other possible way you can try.

Comment: sir getActivity() is showing cannot resolve method error

Comment: solved one of my problems below :) thanks for your help sir

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my switch button state change by implementing onPause() and onResume () methods in my activity, Now the switch state remains the same after changing activities, I have also implemented a bundle in my Activity. I have added it after onCreate method.

**Updated code**

```
 private static Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

   @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        bundle.putBoolean("ToggleButtonState", DayNightt.isChecked());
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        DayNightt.setChecked(bundle.getBoolean("ToggleButtonState",false));
    }
```

only problem left is I have to switch activity to see it implementing, will get over it in sometime.