# Toggle DayNight toggle switch to force theme

Tags: android

I have created a preference activity using android studio's New->Activity->Settings Activity, where I want to toggle Dark/Light theme.

```
<EditTextPreference
    app:key="signature"
    app:title="@string/signature_title"
    app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />

<ListPreference
    app:defaultValue="reply"
    app:entries="@array/reply_entries"
    app:entryValues="@array/reply_values"
    app:key="reply"
    app:title="@string/reply_title"
    app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />

<SwitchPreferenceCompat
    app:key="@string/theme"
    app:title="@string/theme" />
```

Now, in my theme I have:
**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
</resources>
```

Which is changing to Dark/Light with batter status, and not with the button status. How I can achieve this?

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45378151/use-switch-button-to-toggle-daynight-theme) question, but unfortunately, I cant add `app:id` to the toggle button to get the state.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set listener for SwitchPreferenceCompat for that [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019248/switchpreference-onchecked-onclick-listener/11022790) 
and then you can use below function to toggle your day/night mode

```
  public static void toggleTheme() {
    int mode = AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES ? AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO : AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES;
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(mode);
}
```